# Most reliable way to clean List<T> depending on Predicate<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list, predicate

I have `List<T> data` and `Predicate<T> condition.`

What way should I use to clear `data` depending on `condition` result?

- Option 1:

  ```
  var del = data.Where(i => condition);
  data.RemoveAll(i => del.Contains(i));
  ```
- Option 2:

  ```
  var del = data.Where(i => condition);
  for (int i = 0; i < del.Count; i++)
      data.Remove(del[i]);
  ```
- Option 3:

  ```
  var del = data.Where(i => condition);
  foreach (var i in del)
     data.Remove(i);
  ```
- Option 4:

  ```
  data = data.Where(i => !condition);
  ```
- Any other?

Comment: Syntax highlighter is fine when you're not using lists where the items are *just* code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
data.RemoveAll(condition);
```

Note that your fourth option won't work without a call to `ToList()`.